# Как в Laravel возвратить view из функции?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть большой код в моем HomeController-е  после рефакторинга , изменил метод index теперь view должен возвратится так

```
public function index()
{
    $this->showAdminPage();
}


private function showAdminPage()
{ 
    return view('user.admin');
}
```

проблема в том что этот код возвращает пустую страницу.

Как возвратить view() через другой  метод ?
Какой самый правильный стиль возвращения view()  из другого метода ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function index()
{
    return $this->showAdminPage();
}


private function showAdminPage()
{ 
    return view('user.admin');
}
```

---

[Laravel View API Method](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/View/View.html)